# GitHub Variables not available in .NET test file

Tags: github-actions, environment-variables, dotnet, unit-testing

I wrote some F# tests with NUnit, all of them pass just fine when I run them locally. The project is also uploaded on GitHub, there the paths are incorrect.

I wrote as well tests in PowerShell referring to the same paths which works fine.

```
$path = [IO.Path]::Combine("$env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE", '.github', 'workflows', 'file.txt')
```

Using the same principle fails in F#.

```
let path = System.IO.Path.Combine ("home", "runner", "work", ".github", "workflows", "file.txt")
```

OR

```
let sourcePath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("GITHUB_WORKSPACE")
let path = System.IO.Path.Combine (sourcePath, ".github", "workflows", "file.txt")
let path = System.IO.Path.Combine ($"{ github.workspace }", ".github", "workflows", "file.txt")
```

How can I use Github environment variables in .NET test files?